# Adding text to moving Ellipse in C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, text, ellipse

i have a program in C#, wpf.
i have a canvas and on the canvas exists many ellipses that are moving randomly.
Can i add text to each ellipse for example the position of the ellipse ???

Comment: This might help you: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-AU/wpf/thread/27c9eb93-8a32-40d8-b0dd-b441a2496907

Answer (score 0):

Of course, create a user control. The xaml of that user control is a grid that contains your ellipse and your textbox that you set up like you want. Then define the PropertyChanged notifying properties you need, like X,Y, and maybe other text property. Then bind your user control's xaml (Canvas.Top/.Left) to your user control's properties, and you're done.

Comment: i am using canvas not grid and i need to do it not in xaml but in c#

Comment: there's no reason not to do it in xaml... anyway if you insist on doing it in C# then show your code for ellipse and i (or someone else) can help you add your text. If you don't make a user control, you'll have to make custom control.